# Qt: background for QtAbstractItemView (QTableView) while editing an entry

Tags: c++, qt, styling, qtableview

I have the following question.
My `QTableView` has background color set to `black` and color (of contents) to `white`. So, white text appears on a black background - everything seems to be correct. However, when editing (typing in editing mode) content color is changed to black and it becomes completely invisible due to black background, but editing works fine. After confirming - color reverts back to white. How to set color of currently-being-edited text to white (preferably via stylesheets) or stop such change in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `:edit-focus` and/or `:focus` states in your stylesheet.

```
QTableView:edit-focus {
   // style here
}
```

For a list of all available states have a look [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Neither setting `:edit-focus` nor `:focus` states helped (even setting them both). Tried to apply them to `::item` sub-control, which doesn't work too.

Comment: What is the answer to this question? Facing similar problem and :edit-focus or :focus is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Setting palette worked finally.

QPalette palette;

palette.setColor(QPalette::Text, Qt::white);

qApp->setPalette(palette);

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when a cell of the tableview is in the editing state, it is covered by a QLineEdit.You can verify this by setting the background color of QLineEdit to transparent in your stylesheets

```css
QLineEdit{
    background-color: transparent;
  }
```

After setting, you will find that the cell is in the editing state, with a text being edited and a displayed text.

Therefore, the solution to this problem is to set the style of QLineEdit in your stylesheets.

```css
QLineEdit {
    background-color: rgb(68,67,49);
    border: 0px;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:SimHei;
    color:#ADB5BD;
    qproperty-alignment: AlignCenter;
}
```